# Get value on click of tab panel in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

```
          <div class="col-lg-6">
                <a-tabs tabPosition="right">
                    <a-tab-pane v-for="config in listData" :tab="config.name" :key="config._id">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="card">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="text-black mb-3"><strong>{{ config.name }}</strong></h4>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </a-tab-pane>
                </a-tabs>
            </div>


<script>
    const listData = [
      {
        _id: '35324',
        name: 'product 1',
      },
      {
        _id: '345434',
        name: 'product 2',
      },
   ];
   created() {
      //I want to get the `config.name` value here every time I click on `tab-pane
   }
</script>
```

I am working on tab-pane in vuejs. I want when I click on tab-pane I get the `name` of that pane in `created`. I'm really stuck. Please give me your opinion. Thank you

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but created() is a hook, maybe you need another variable in the data() function to hold the tab name. Since it seems that you're using Ant Design Vue, you can use the event tabClick to trigger a method passing the tab name to store in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd like to do that (strange to use that kind of hook this way) but as said before, you may want to use a variable and a click-event function to do that.

[image]

In your template :

`<a-tab-pane v-for="config in listData" :tab="config.name" :key="config._id" @tabClick="setTabName(config.name)">`

...

`<h4 class="text-black mb-3"><strong>{{ config.name }}</strong></h4>`

...

`</a-tab-pane>`

in your script :

`tabName = '';`

`setTabName(name) { this.tabName = name; }`

---